# Class.forName () to search for class in another project

Tags: java, algorithm, class, reflection

I have a project A with package inside it as follows:
A/src/mypackage/class/Class1.java

Then i have another Project B with package as follows:

B/src/mypackage/class/Class2.java

I need to use Class.forName() in class inside project A and get Class2 . But Class.forName(mypackage.class.Class2) throws class not found Exception .

Does any one know any workaround for this?

Comment: Is project B in project A's classpath?

Comment: Yes . it is in class path

Answer (score 1):

If your `B/src/mypackage/class/Class2.java` is in "project A"'s classpath, you are probably passing a bad argument for the class' name.

You should use:

```
full.package.FileName[$NestedClassName]
```

... where ...

- The full package is a dot-separated package descriptor (i.e.
  `mypackage.class`).
- The class name is the name of the class for that file (i.e.
  `Class2`).
- The optional nested class name would apply for a class within
  `Class2`, e.g. `Class2$MyNestedClass`.

Ultimately, your call should look like:

```
try {
    Class.forName("mypackage.class.Class2");
}
// TODO handle
catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
}
```